# Image with Animation CSS + Submit Button Hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have an Animation with Animate.css

```
$('#log-circle').addClass('animated flipInY');
```

This animation occurs on Page Load - no problem

But I want to reload the same animation when the user hover a submit button.

My initial idea is to reload the animation on CLICK, (if its possible will be perfect) - but I think that animation will never occurs because with the click on submit button the page will change to another..

then I'm trying to reload the animation on hover - like:

```
<script>
$( ".log-btn" ).hover( function() {
    $('#log-circle').addClass('animated flipOutY');
});

</script>
```

but nothing happens..

IMPORTANT: THE ANIMATION OCCURS iN A IMAGE. (not in the button)

thank for all help!

http://jsfiddle.net/j03hgtae

Daniel

Comment: Can you add an example of your relevant code in jsfiddle

Comment: You need to add some `html` and `css` atleast..

Comment: @DANIEL Can include `css` animation at Question ? _"but nothing happens.."_ Are `animated` ,  `flipOutY` classes removed after animation completes ?

Comment: hi guys! first of all tks for your time!! @PaulGraffam, - https://jsfiddle.net/j03hgtae/ - here is the jsfiddle. The code is very simple. Only a submit button (inside form) - and an image. (in this case is an "avatar" image) - the page is like Gmail login page. tks a lot! In the jsfiddle ONLOAD as I said its OK. But I want to put the same animation when you hover the submit button. tks!!

Comment: @GuruprasadRao tks for your help! here is the jsfiddle: jsfiddle.net/j03hgtae

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `.addClass().removeClass()` won't actually trigger the animation. The easiest way to re-trigger a CSS animation is to clone the element.

```
$('#log-circle').addClass('animated flipInY');

$('#log-btn').hover( function() {
  // Clone the original element
  var element = $('#log-circle'),  
        clone = element.clone(true);
  // Insert the cloned element before the original element
  element.before(clone);
  // Remove the original element
  element.remove();
});
```

[See the updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j03hgtae/2/)

And, as stated in the first answer, you were targeting `.log-btn` instead of `#log-btn`.

Comment: Hi @Stef - first of all tks for your time and help! Great answer! Clean, and fits 100% on my script. Works great!! Tks a lot!!! :D

Comment: I'm just change the hover for onmouseover to prevent another reload when "unhover" the button. I put: $('#log-btn').on("mouseover", function() {. PERFECT! Exactly what I want! tks @Stef :D

Answer (score 0):

You are targeting `.log-btn`, but no such class exists.

```
 <button type="submit" **class="btn btn-sm input-group-sm**" style="width: 160px;  margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 10px" **id="log-btn"** name="log-btn">Login</button>

$( ".log-btn" ).hover( function() {
   $('#log-circle').RemoveClass('animated flipOutY');
   $('#log-circle').addClass('animated flipOutY');
});
```

Instead, you should be targeting `#log-btn`, as the button (see below) is using an ID identifier as opposed to a Class identifier.

```
$( "#log-btn" ).hover( function() {
    $('#log-circle').RemoveClass('animated flipOutY');
    $('#log-circle').addClass('animated flipOutY');
});
```

Your solution is to replace `( ".log-btn" ).hover` with `( "#log-btn" ).hover`. Alternatively, consider adding a class named "log-btn" to the button element.

Comment: Hi @david-lerner tks for your time and patience to help me. I'm not a jquery expert and I'm always be confused about # or . identifier on the script. (now I know that # is for ID and . for class - but I always test with booth. And with # didnt works too. The solution is what Stef post above. Fits perfectly. Tks for your help! :D